# Java.IO.FileNotFoundException Handling

Tags: java

When doing this, I am trying to make it "dummy proof" for my coworkers, so if they put in a file path instead of a file - the program doesn't stop so that they can just keep going in the application - it'll just ask them again. However currently

```
FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\usersname\Desktop\userImports\current (Access is denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\usersname\Desktop\userImports\current (Access is denied)
```

How do I work for this? I don't want it to crash like this, I'd rather it just say, "thats not a file - please try again"

How do I better handle file not found exceptions?

```
 File f;
            do {
                System.out.print("Please give me the " + type + "file: " );
                String file = console.nextLine();
                f = new File(file);
            } while (!f.exists());
            Scanner readMe = null;
            try {
                readMe = new Scanner(f);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return readMe;
        }
```

Comment: *You're* printing the stack trace inside your `catch` block. Instead of that, you could print whatever message you want.

Comment: You could work with the [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class. it has several options you might be looking for, like [File#exists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()),
 [File#isFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile()) or [File#canWrite](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canWrite())

Comment: "Access is denied" may comes if we are giving any file which is not allowed to be accessed from outside program. Make sure ani-one can access that file

Comment: use the isFile() and isDirectory() methods to distinguish between files and folders. are you sure you are giving exact file path/name in input

Comment: Class File has isDirectory() and exists() methods

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understood what you exactly want but this is my answer to what I understood : 
Just loop while u don't find the file and you can also add a counter like after 5 times u exit the program.

```
File f;
boolean found = false ; 

  while (!found) {

        do {
            System.out.print("Please give me the " + type + "file: " );
            String file = console.nextLine();
            f = new File(file);
        } while (!f.exists());

        Scanner readMe = null;

        try {

            readMe = new Scanner(f);
            found = true ; 

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            found = false ; 
            System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());

            system.out.printl  ( "A problem occured while loading the file please try again ");
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }

  return readMe;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Access is denied" means that the file does exist but the user who ran the program is not allowed to access - in your case read - it. It could be, i.a., that the user does not have the necessary authority, or that the file is being held by another program.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use canRead() instead of exists()

```
do {
  ...
} while (!f.canRead());
```